# Is there a way to target only images within the loop?

Tags: loop, images, get-posts

I'm new to WordPress and I'm trying to target specific parts of the content.

I understand how to grab the title with `get_title()` — **is there something similar for images**?

Answer (score 0):

That depends.

There is `the_post_thumbnail` which will echo the "featured" image and `get_children` can grab all attachments.

Certain kinds of images aren't attached though, so you can't easily get those.

## Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children